Is there a special meaning to "||" in passage references?
I was studying the bible using an app (German). Some verses in the app also reference other verses, just like a regular bible.

I am wondering how to interpret this notation of references. Take this example (found on 1 Kings 6:38):

1 - 38 || 2 Chr 3,1 - 14 / 3: Ez 40,48f. / 5: Ez 41,5 - 7 / 12: 2Sam 7,8 - 16 / 20: Ez 41,4 / 31 - 35: Ez 41,21 - 25

I understand that the individual references are separated by a / and then there are pairs of one or more verses together with a reference for that verse.
Note however that one time the verse range and its reference are separated by ||:
1 - 38 || 2 Chr 3,1 - 14

Another time, the verse range and its reference are separated by a colon:
31 - 35: Ez 41,21 - 25

Does || have a certain meaning as opposed to : or is it even a common notation used in Bibles?

Welcome to the site, BenjyTec  I'm just wondering if this question might be better suited to the Stack German Language site? https://german.stackexchange.com/

@Anne I know that the || is not a common construct in German, that's why I rather expected it to be something related to biblical references itself.

According to the SBL Handbook of Style, twin slashes "//" are to be use to denote parallel texts, such as parallel Gospel passages, parallels between the Gospel of Thomas and Q, etc. I suspect that these are also to be used when there are parallels between the historical books of the OT (e.g., Kings and Chronicles). Perhaps the Germans (or this particular publisher) instead use parallel vertical lines. (I know that my publisher had a few of its own quirky little conventions.)
I'm going to guess that the number followed by a colon is highlighting references which are pertinent to a specific verse in the above passage.

This makes total sense! Especially the hint regarding historical books. At further inspection, I found that the || seems only to be used in the books of Samuel, Kings and Chronicles.
